# How to insert multiple rows of data from listview to linq to sql VB.Net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, linq, listview

i'm a newbie in programming vb.net, I'm making a simple point of sale
I want to insert multiple rows of data from listview to linq to sql, here is the code:

```
Private Sub Save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Save.Click

    Dim db As New PenjualanDataContext
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
        Dim TransaksiBaru As New Transaksi With {.Dibayar = Dibayar.Text, .Faktur = FakturTextBox.Text, .Harga = HargaComboBox.Text, .Jumlah = JumlahTextBox.Text, .Kembali = Kembali.Text, .Kode_Barang = Kode_BarangComboBox.Text, .Nama_Barang = Nama_BarangComboBox.Text, .SubTotal = SubTotalTextBox.Text, .Tanggal = TanggalDateTimePicker.Text, .Total = TotalTextBox.Text}
        db.Transaksis.InsertOnSubmit(TransaksiBaru)
        db.SubmitChanges()
    Next

End Sub
```

I cannot save the data to linq to sql.....

Comment: *I cannot save the data to linq to sql.* That can mean anything. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

**First**, it is faster to Submit Changes one time when all record are inserted in the context.

**Second**, it is recommended to use `Using` method

**Third**, you are looping over `ListView1.SelectedItems` and not using `item` object returned by the loop. i think that you are missing something in your code

Try modifying your code to the following:

```
Private Sub Save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Save.Click

    Using db As New PenjualanDataContext

        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems

            Dim TransaksiBaru As New Transaksi With {.Dibayar = Dibayar.Text, .Faktur = FakturTextBox.Text, .Harga = HargaComboBox.Text, .Jumlah = JumlahTextBox.Text, .Kembali = Kembali.Text, .Kode_Barang = Kode_BarangComboBox.Text, .Nama_Barang = Nama_BarangComboBox.Text, .SubTotal = SubTotalTextBox.Text, .Tanggal = TanggalDateTimePicker.Text, .Total = TotalTextBox.Text}

            db.Transaksis.InsertOnSubmit(TransaksiBaru)

        Next

         db.SubmitChanges()

     End Using

End Sub
```

*You can refer to the following [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386941(v=vs.110).aspx) to read more about inserting Rows using Linq-to-SQL*

Comment: To OP: You should be populating properties of `Transaksi` from `item`..

Comment: Wow, it works, thanks Hadi, you' re a big help!!! And if I want to print the listview data, can I be able to use Using Method also?

Comment: Happy to help. Yes you can use it. If this answer worked you have to [accept it](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) else give me a feedback